# full text view not return result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a view with full index on fullname. when i run

```
SELECT * 
FROM vwPersonSearch
```

it returns rows

when I run:

```
SELECT *
FROM vwPersonSearch
WHERE [Full name] ='Mark RUSH')
```

It returns one row

when I run:

```
SELECT * 
FROM vwPersonSearch
WHERE contains([Full name],'"Mark*" AND "RUSH*"')
```

It doesn't return any row. Why so ?

Comment: What does `SELECT * FROM    vwPersonSearch  WHERE contains([Full name],'"Mark*"')` return?

Comment: It returns 10 rows. it is result of join of tblPerson and tblRegistered

Comment: if you change it to an `OR` instead of an `AND` do you still get 10 rows?

Comment: @Abe sorry it doesn't return any result with SELECT * FROM vwPersonSearch WHERE contains([Full name],'"Mark*"')

Comment: @DotnetSparrow - Check two things (1) - check the status of your full text catalog (in SQL 2005 this is under your datablas->Storage->Full Text Catalogs: Properties). This will show you the last population date. (2) very unlikley, but you can check the noise***.txt file in ...\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\FTData to make sure that Mark or Rush are not listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)(See Examples c and D) your usage of the asterisk indicates you are searching for strings that are prefixed with both the terms Mark and RUSH. I don't think this will return anything.  Try changing it to this:

```
SELECT * FROM vwPersonSearch  WHERE contains([Full name],'"Mark*" AND "RUSH"')
```

This will search for strings that are prefixed with Mark and also contain RUSH.